Does the Cosmic Hunt myth imply the existence of a Proto-Human language?
I'm talking about this. Now I don't know much about linguistics, but this myth is supposedly 15000 years old, way older than Proto Indo European, for example. It's also present in a lot of cultures with unrelated languages. Doesn't that imply that the original story must've been told in a common language spoken by the predecessors of all of these cultures? Could this also mean that PIE and other unrelated language groups all descended from this "Proto Human" language?

We know that myth can diffuse across linguistic families (especially clear in the historical era with the spread of proselytising religions such as Buddhism, Christianity, & Islam and their accompanying mythologies), so even if we accept that this myth is genuinely a shared inheritance, that need not imply linguistic unity.
Additionally, many elements of comparative mythology suffer from poor levels of falsifiability, making it hard to tell what comparisons are actually due to genuine shared inheritance, and what is simply coincidence.
It's also worth noting that most linguists consider monogenesis of language (i.e. the existence of a proto-world language) more likely than polygenesis (at least outside the cases of creoles, where the traditional view has been that they are genuinely new languages without simple genetic inheritance from any previous language), just that this is entirely beyond the reach of the evidence available to us and so fundamentally unprovable, making it uninteresting scientifically.
It's also worth noting that there has been research on whether Neanderthals may have had speech. This is highly speculative, having to draw conclusions from their anatomy and presence or absence of symbolic representations in their material culture, but the consensus seems to be that they likely did have something we would recognise as qualitatively the same as human language (the high levels of interbreeding would also seem to suggest this). With that in mind, it's plausible that our proto-world language might predate the split between humans and Neanderthals, and so calling it proto-human might not be accurate.

Interesting, thanks!

Stories, like memes, are known to cross linguistics boundaries pretty freely; there is some solid research on European fables and fairy tales classifying motifs and stories with instances in many different languages. So a common story does not imply a common language at all.
And, giving some dates of orientation: Proto-World, if it is a thing at all, was about 300k year ago (at least), before the split of Home sapiens and Homo neanderthalensis, as evidenced by genetics. This is quite distant from the assumed origin of the Cosmic Hunt myth 15k years ago.
